# problems with onCellLocationChanged

Tags: android, telephonymanager, phone-state-listener

I need to start service when my device change cell connection and I presume to do that with `onCellLocationChanged()` implements below but the beeps start only if I receive incoming calls...

my listener:

```
public class CellLocationListener extends PhoneStateListener {

    @Override
    public void onCellLocationChanged(CellLocation location) {
        super.onCellLocationChanged(location);

        int cid = 0;
        int lac = 0;

        if (location != null) {
            if (location instanceof GsmCellLocation) {
                cid = ((GsmCellLocation) location).getCid();
                lac = ((GsmCellLocation) location).getLac();
            }
            else if (location instanceof CdmaCellLocation) {
                cid = ((CdmaCellLocation) location).getBaseStationId();
                lac = ((CdmaCellLocation) location).getSystemId();
            }
        }

        String cellInfo = Integer.toString(lac)+"-"+Integer.toString(cid);

        Log.v("logg","CELL CHANGED:"+cellInfo);
    }
}
```

I've used the same cellInfo on mainactivity and when I start it cellInfo chages its value but no beeps from broadcas receiver....

on manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_UPDATES" />

<receiver android:name="dado.auto3gdataswitch.CellChangeReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

my broadcastReceiver

```
  public class CellChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

     TelephonyManager telephony;

     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        CellLocationListener phoneListener = new CellLocationListener();
        telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        telephony.listen(phoneListener, CellLocationListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

        Toast.makeText(context, "ON receiver", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.beep); 
        mp.start();
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {      
                mp.stop();
                mp.release();
            }
        });

        Log.v("logg","onreceiver");

    }
}
```

I hear a beep only if I receive incoming call and not if I change cell....

What's wrong??

Comment: how do you emulate cell change? have you tried to send the necessary broadcast manually?

Comment: I may be missing something, but you're not doing anything when you receive new cell location.  I don't see you actually doing anything useful with the new location - only creating a string variable containing this location and not even using that variable anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've foud a better solution!!!

in my mainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final TelephonyManager telm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    int events = PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CELL_LOCATION;
    telm.listen(phoneStateListener, events);

.....
}

private final PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCellLocationChanged(CellLocation location) {
        super.onCellLocationChanged(location);

        int cid = 0;
        int lac = 0;

        if (location != null) {
            if (location instanceof GsmCellLocation) {
                cid = ((GsmCellLocation) location).getCid();
                lac = ((GsmCellLocation) location).getLac();
            }
            else if (location instanceof CdmaCellLocation) {
                cid = ((CdmaCellLocation) location).getBaseStationId();
                lac = ((CdmaCellLocation) location).getSystemId();
            }
        }

        String cellBase = Integer.toString(lac)+"-"+Integer.toString(cid);

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), cellBase, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.v("logg", "cell:"+cellBase);

        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.beep);    
        mp.start();
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                mp.stop();
                mp.release();
            }
        });
    }       
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You are listening to `CellLocationListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE`, but you should listen for `CellLocationListener.LISTEN_CELL_LOCATION`. And if you want the sound to be played on cell change, you should move the corresponding code to the `onCellLocationChanged`. And your cell change listener will be registered only when `android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE` will be received.

Comment: android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE send intent only on call in/out... which action can i use??

Comment: @user3133243 It depends on the needs. You can use `BOOT_COMPLETED`, for example. Or you can drop receiver and add listener at the some activity start.

Comment: i need to send intent when cell change. if i use the up code inside an activity, it runs perfec but activity needs to be open... i need an action like android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE but for telephony...

Comment: @user3133243 there is no such intent action at the system, so you should think what's the best stage when to add `CellLocationListener`. For example, it can be done at the first start of the app

Comment: like this? IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(my.custom.intent);        registerReceiver(new CellChangeReceiver(), filter);

Comment: @user3133243 yes, it can be also be done like this, and like you've posted in your answer as well. Or you can listen for `android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE`, it also reflects connection change (but in terms of data)

Comment: @user3133243 if this answer helped you, please accept it and close the question